# Is is possible to secure a directory on Apache with a custom form?

Tags: apache

Is is possible to secure a directory on Apache with a custom form? I have a directory full of static HTML files, it is basically a full static site. I want to secure this site with a password.

I know I can use .htaccess but I would much rather have a custom form/database to secure the site. I know how to code in PHP well enough to create the form, database and do the authentication. What I don't know is how to tell Apache to redirect to that form if the user is not authenticated.

**UPDATE:** I would be fine using other authentication modules. I'm looking for a system similar to IIS Forms authentication. If the user is not logged in, visiting any file in the directory will redirect to a login form. Once logged in they can view any of the files in the directory.

Comment: Yes, rewrite all requests to this directory to a PHP/Python/whatever language script that does the authentication. That script will print the contents of the requested file if the user is allowed access, otherwise show a login form. Apache does not know anything about the authentication, it simply rewrites all requests.

Comment: @DanGrossman - Apache has to know something about authentication and sessions for .htaccess to work.

Comment: No it doesn't, why would you say that? HTTP basic authentication is entirely stateless, there are no sessions on the server.

Comment: @DanGrossman - If it didn't how would it know to let the visitor have access to the files .htaccess was protecting.

Comment: Because every request contains the username and password encoded in an `Authorization` HTTP header. The browser does that. Apache does not maintain any state about authentication between requests. It doesn't need to in order to do what you want either. I didn't make some exotic suggestion, it's common practice.

Comment: @DanGrossman - For every request after authentication to every file in the directory/subdirectory the browsers keeps sending the user/password? That seems wrong.

Comment: Yes, thats what it does. Feel free to 'wikipedia it' or read RFC 2617.

Comment: @DanGrossman - wow, learn something new every day. Seems like IIS is one-up on Apache here.

Comment: I don't think you're qualified to make that statement. No offense.

Comment: @DanGrossman - None taken. This could be done with forms authentication on IIS though.

Comment: Just like HTTP basic/digest is not the only authentication IIS can provide, there are dozens of authentication modules for Apache as well. Ex. http://serverfault.com/questions/63396/apache-authentication-using-forms. That said, the two-line rewrite rule to a script that does authentication is pretty common too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pseudocode follows:

```
if user authenticated:
   read a file and output into browser (or return 404)
else:
   show the form
end
```

The following `.htaccess` will rewrite every request to `.html` files into `index.php`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule \.html$ /index.php [QSA,L]
```

You'll find the requested `.html` filename in `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`.

(Most of known PHP frameworks uses this or similar approach. There isn't anything fancy in this.)